# Php Command Line Output on the fly

Tags: command-line, php

I am writing a command line php script which does some output to the console window, its all look good only issues is when i type

```
php myfilename.php -....
```

in the console window, ONLY AFTER its fully executed it outputs the result to the window ..

Wht i want is to do this on the fly like below

```
customer id: 1223 skipped.
customer id: 22233 added..
```

...etc

another question is adding \n\r to the printf functions didn't go to a new line ...

any idea on these issues..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the [Windows-style end-of-line marker is `\r\n`, not `\n\r`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_line). Not many systems ever used `\n\r`, but they are rare enough that you can forget about them now.

Second, chances are good the output is being *block buffered* -- you can either use [`ob_implicit_flush(1)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) to automatically insert a [`flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) command after every output command. Or, you could call `flush()` manually, when you need to flush output.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably due to [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). You can use `ob_flush()` to flush the buffer manually when needed.

As for your second issue, the correct sequence for newline on Microsoft Windows is `"\r\n"`, not the other way around.

Comment: first problem seems to be solved, even if i used "\r\n" it doenst out put new line in the console but if i put enter in the code its works fine..

Answer (score 3):

About the End-Of-Line marker, **always use PHP predefined constant** `PHP_EOL`; **it is correctly set based on your platform**, so you do not have to worry is it right or wrong.

For the [Enter] issue, it could be the output buffering is on. Add this simple test in your script:

```
function test()
{
    $state = array(' added', ' skipped');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
    {
        echo 'customer id: ' . rand(1, 1000) . $state[rand(0, 1)] . PHP_EOL;
        usleep(50000); // slow it a bit to see the line by line output
    }
}

// without ob -------------------------------------------

$start = microtime(true);
test();
echo 'Finished in ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 2) . PHP_EOL . str_repeat('-', 78) . PHP_EOL;
sleep(1);

// with ob ----------------------------------------------

$start = microtime(true);
ob_start(); // if called somewhere at the top in your script

// some previous code...
echo 'Line 1'.PHP_EOL.'Line 2'.PHP_EOL.uniqid().PHP_EOL;

// flush the buffer and stop ob
// this will echo whatever is in the output buffer!
//ob_end_flush();

// or, store the current buffer content in a variable and use it later
$output = ob_get_clean();

test();
echo $output;
echo 'Finished in ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 2) . PHP_EOL . str_repeat('-', 78) . PHP_EOL;

// you could start buffering again, if needed
ob_start();
```

For output control functions see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php. They are very powerful tools.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Above post solved a problem I was banging my head over for days even if not directly related.  I thought I had a buffer problem.  Turned out all I needed to do was add PHP_EOL to the end of my echo statement to get the stdout to go to my log output.  The simplest thing that I wasted hours and hours on.